Boost upgrade from 1.77 to 1.85 compiler error
I have upgraded boost (see title) and I failed to compile to code due to some issue in Boost.JOSN. Given the code below were successfully compiled with Boost 1.77 and fail with 1.85:
namespace product_namespace {
enum class Command {
    enum values...
};

// tag_invoke implementation in source file, make no sense here 
Command tag_invoke(const boost::json::value_to_tag<Command>& vt, boost::json::value const& jv);
void tag_invoke(const boost::json::value_from_tag& vt, boost::json::value& jv, const Command& command);

inline boost::json::value Digest() const {
    Command Cmd = Command::SomeValue;

    return boost::json::value{
        {"cmd", Cmd}, // Compiler error here. See below
        ...
    };
};


Can anybody help me, how to solve this issue? Even what could be the rout-cause upgrading the version from 1.77 to 1.85?
Thank you
Full compiler error log (I had to modify the original log, to remove some company proprietary information):
In file included from <built-in>:455:
In file included from .../cmake_pch.hxx:5:
In file included from .../pch.h:57:
In file included from ...thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json.hpp:15:
In file included from ...thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/array.hpp:1762:
In file included from ...thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:4317:
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/impl/value_ref.hpp:36:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::json::value'
    return value(
           ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value_ref.hpp:204:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::json::value_ref::from_const<product_namespace::Command>' requested here
        : cf_{&from_const<T>, &t}
               ^
.../Request.h:189:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::json::value_ref::value_ref<product_namespace::Command>' requested here
        {Request::NameOfCmd, Cmd},
                             ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:247:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'const boost::json::value' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:305:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::value' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:329:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'std::nullptr_t' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:384:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'signed char' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:406:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'short' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:428:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'int' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:450:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'long' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:472:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'long long' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:494:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'unsigned char' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:516:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'unsigned short' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:538:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'unsigned int' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:560:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'unsigned long' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:582:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'unsigned long long' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:604:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'double' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:629:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:656:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:711:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'const boost::json::string' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:738:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::string' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:774:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::string_kind_t' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:828:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'const boost::json::array' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:855:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::array' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:891:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::array_kind_t' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:945:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'const boost::json::object' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:972:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::object' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:1008:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'boost::json::object_kind_t' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:1056:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const product_namespace::Command' to 'std::initializer_list<value_ref>' for 1st argument
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:362:5: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same<product_namespace::Command, bool>::value' was not satisfied [with T = product_namespace::Command]
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:78:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'ua', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:85:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'uo', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:174:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'sp', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(storage_ptr sp) noexcept
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:201:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(pilfered<value> other) noexcept
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:222:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(value const& other)
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:271:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(value&& other) noexcept;
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:687:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:805:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(array other) noexcept
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:922:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but 2 arguments were provided
    value(object other) noexcept
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:91:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
    value(
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:153:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    value() noexcept
    ^
.../thirdparty/boost/include/boost/json/value.hpp:99:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 2 were provided
    value(
    ^

Solution
Finally, I think, found the explanation / solution:
https://github.com/boostorg/json/issues/823#issuecomment-1361407806
According to this bug report, the original behavioral was a bug regarding to Boost's authors

You've posted only the first line of the compiler error, posting the whole compiler message (it's probably quite long) might give some of the experts here a better idea of what the problem is.

Also posting definitions of Cmd, Request etc will help. The more information you can supply the more information anyone wishing to answer the question has to work with.

What compiler?  I suspect newer versions of Boost require C++11 or later.  I hit a similar wall recently as well.

When posting compiler errors please show a [mre] that reproduces that errror

looks like it breaks in boost 1.81 https://godbolt.org/z/exE87a1Ed, maybe due to https://github.com/boostorg/json/pull/686

Are you sure that Command is not an enum class, which boost::json doesn't support? Although I must admit I never tried it... I just convert them to integer and back for the json.

@ChristianStieber  Command is an enum class but the tag_invoke functions should convert them?

@AlanBirtles oh... yeah, maybe. It wouldn't really make sense to only fail in newer versions anyway... replacing "Cmd" with 55 makes it compile, though, so it's something in that magic boost infrastructure with the initializer lists and/or the conversions. Also note that using boost::json::value_from(Cmd) explicitly also seems to work... but then again, if it worked before...

I have updated my original question, posted the answer. I don't know, how should I highlight it for further. Maybe this can help others later

I'm surprised this compiled. I thought value_from was only ever explicitly invoked.
Here's with Boost 1.77:
Live On Compiler Explorer
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;

namespace X {
    enum Command { SomeValue, b, c };

    Command tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Command>, json::value const&) {
        return {}; // TODO
    }
    void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& jv, Command const& command) {
        switch (command) {
            case SomeValue: jv = "SomeValue"; break;
            case b: jv = "b"; break;
            case c: jv = "c"; break;
        }
    }

} // namespace X

int main() {
    X::Command       Cmd = X::Command::SomeValue;
    std::vector<int> vv{1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << json::value{{"cmd", Cmd}} << std::endl;
    std::cout << json::value{{"cmd", Cmd}, {"vec", vv}} << std::endl;
}

We see
{"cmd":"SomeValue"}
{"cmd":"SomeValue","vec":[1,2,3]}

While I didn't expect that, but it seems to make sense.
Boost 1.78-1.80 work. Boost 1.81 no longer compiles it. The change log does mention some changes around builtin value_to/value_from support, but nothing indicating an intended change for the constructors.
Looking a the the documentation for the constructors no mention of the tag_invoke conversions exists.
Looking at the implementation, the initializer list causes this overload of value_ref constructor to be used. This causes value_ref::make_value to invoke down the line:

Which ends up dispatching through
template<class T>
value
value_ref::
from_const(
    void const* p,
    storage_ptr sp)
{
    return value(
        *reinterpret_cast<
            T const*>(p),
        std::move(sp));
}

Which - surprisingly - ends up in the constructor json::value::value(int, storage_ptr). This is hardly surprising because the T in from_const is X::Command, which implicitly converts to int.

This is with GCC 14.1 and Boost 1.86 (git@112dc7298874f5e1).
Clang 18.1.5 has same results.

Minimizing
Given the above analysis, we can say the initializer lists and from_const factory function template are immaterial. Let's directly invoke the value constructor:
std::cout << json::value(X::Command::SomeValue) << std::endl;

Now, what happens on 1.77? Indeed this has the same behaviour, printing 0.
Difference
Indeed, in 1.77 const_from is implemented in terms of value_from!
template<class T>
value
value_ref::
from_const(
    void const* p,
    storage_ptr sp)
{
    return value_from(
        *reinterpret_cast<
            T const*>(p),
        std::move(sp));
}

The change was introduced in dff6f8d4, as part of PR#686 Refactoring of conversion functions. You can raise an issue at https://github.com/boostorg/json/issues to ask

whether the change was intentional
what the rationale was for this breaking change

